# How to change color Image into black/white in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show color image in black/white, how to do it using colorFilter in android jetpack compose?

```
    Image(
        painter = painter, contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentScale = scale,
        colorFilter = null
    )
```

Answer (score 36):

You can also use `ColorFilter.tint(color = ...)`

```
Image(
        painter = painter, contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentScale = scale,
        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground)
    )
```

Comment: Well, this will only result in grayscaling if you didn't modify the default theme. ;) Better use `Color.Black` instead of `MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground`/`MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground`.

Answer (score 19):

We can easily achieve that by using colorMatrix:

```
    val matrix = ColorMatrix()
    matrix.setToSaturation(0F)
    
    Image(
        painter = painter, contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        contentScale = scale,
        colorFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(matrix)
    )
```

Comment: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/android-image-color-change-with-colormatrix-e927d7fb6eb4 - small guide to understand color matrix

Comment: Another syntax for the above would be `colorFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(ColorMatrix().apply { setToSaturation(0f) })
`